# Which textbooks contain info on Bessel functions & their use as basis functions?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematical-physics, mathematics, eigenvalue

> As an exercise my research mentor assigned me to solve the following set of equations for the constants $a$, $b$, and $c$ at the bottom. The function $f(r)$ should be a basis function for a cylindrical geometry with boundary conditions such that the value of $J$ is 0 at the ends of the cylinder.

I'm having trouble finding textbooks with the information I must know to solve these equations. I've looked through "Mathematical Methods" by Hassani & "Math Methods for Theoretical Physics" by Morse, perhaps I over looked something but if anyone can point me in the right direction I would be very grateful. From what I understand thus far, the functions should be some variant of Bessel functions, and this method is that of basis functions.

[image]

Comment: The book on Electrodynamics by J.D.Jackson has nice applications in Electrostatics where Bessel functions appear in situations with cylindrical symmetry. Commonly used (undergraduate) textbooks for Mathematical Methods are the books by Arfken and Riley-Hobson-Spence.

Comment: Wait, can't you just use variants of Gauss' and Stokes' laws?  For instance, is a the integral over a volume $\Omega$ of the divergence of $\vec{f}(\vec{r})$?  This may simplify things significantly.  Anyways, I was going to suggest Jackson as well, since he has numerous discussions of Bessel functions.

Comment: The problem I have is not in evaluating the integral in which case it is trivial. It is in finding a function f(r) which describes the cylindrical geometry.

Comment: Could one of the mods please explain why this is not off-topic? I'm not trying to get this question closed, I'm just trying to understand the rules.

Answer (score 1):

All these functions (and more) are documented in the [Handbook of mathematical functions by Abramowitz and Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/) (which is a staple of many professor libraries)